# Mongoengine documents are saved without fields after `switch_collection`

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I have a very strange behaviour when saving documents after using the [`switch_collection`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.Document.switch_collection) method.

Can be reproduced using the following code:

```py
import mongoengine as me


class ObjectA(me.Document):
    name = me.StringField()


def test_strange_behaviour():
    a_0 = ObjectA(name="a_0")
    a_0.save()

    a_1 = ObjectA(name="a_1")
    a_1.save()

    a_1.switch_collection("new_collection", keep_created=False)
    a_1.id = a_0.id
    a_1.save()

    print(a_1._collection)
    print(a_1._collection.find_one(a_1.id))
```

When calling the `test_strange_behaviour` function, the code prints something like that:

```
Collection(Database(MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, read_preference=Primary(), connecttimeoutms=30000, heartbeatfrequencyms=3000, ssl=False), 'engine'), 'new_collection')
{'_id': ObjectId('5dc57611dba04ca06410e477')}
```

As you can see, the last print shows that the document created on the `new_collection` collection contains only the `_id` field, and not the `name` field. The same thing happens if `keep_created` is `True`.

Why does that happen? Is something wrong with this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After attributing `a_0.id` to `a_1.id`, you should save it with `force_insert=True`, otherwise you're just updating `a_1`.